# mysql trigger or event to execute the update after amount of time (60 seconds)

Tags: php, mysql

I created the login webpage with `PHP` and `MySQL`. When login unsuccessful the `MySQL` database will record the attempt. every 60 seconds the attempt will reset to zero. After 3 attempts the webpage will not allow me to log in that username.

I have 2 `MySQL` table called

> userdb (username, password and attempts)

and

> loginA (user and loginAttempt)

I managed to record the number of attempt in `userdb` if I fail to login. For the `loginAttempt` is used to cause the trigger to change the `userdb` back to attempt zero. I managed caused the attempt to reset to zero but it is not 60 seconds. it happens right away. If I added the do sleep (60) it will just be frozen for 60 seconds on the webpage. I wonder is there any way to activate the trigger after 60 seconds without loading for 60 seconds on the webpage?

MYSQL code

```
CREATE TRIGGER login_condition
AFTER UPDATE ON loginA FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DO SLEEP(40);
 UPDATE userdb set attempts = 0 where username=new.username; 
END
```

PHP code (this use to activate the trigger)

```
$query = "UPDATE loginA SET date='$date' WHERE username='$user'";
                storeData($conn,$query);
```

I want this trigger to activate after 60 seconds with affecting the webpage loading.

Comment: Call instead of updating a stored procedure witch undates after 60 seconds like your trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the time of the last attempt in the `loginA` table.

Instead of a trigger, use the Event Scheduler to perform a query every few minutes. The query can reset the attempts to 0 if it has been more than 60 seconds since the last attempt.

```
CREATE EVENT reset_login
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
    UPDATE userdb AS u
    JOIN loginA AS l ON u.username = l.username
    SET u.attempts = 0
    WHERE u.attempts > 0 AND l.last_attempt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```